# How to enable modern look and feel of tool bar for Win32 Application?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user-interface, comctl32

Recently I started learning GUI programming based on Win32 API. When I add tool bar control (from **comctl32.lib**) to my simple application I find it looks flat while the menu bar has more "Windows 7 friendly" 3D look and feel (white glow at the top and vertical gray gradient from top to bottom). The difference makes it look wired.

[image: Default ToolBar style]

However, I find many other applications have consistent look and feel for both menu bar and tool bar. Eg. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and [Notepad 2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html).

[image: Notepad++]
[image: Notepad 2]

I've read some official documents and tried the solution, such as [Visual Styles Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270423(v=vs.85).aspx), [Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx), however, it only enables the flat button style (compared to the old Win98 solid button style). It made no difference with the style I got in the first picture.

I tried to read Notepad++'s source code. Found [ToolBar.cpp](http://svn.tuxfamily.org/viewvc.cgi/notepadplus_repository/trunk/PowerEditor/src/WinControls/ToolBar/ToolBar.cpp?revision=896&view=markup) and made some changes to my code accordingly, but nothing changed. I think I was lost in the code base.

Here is my code of calling `InitCommonControlsEx` and creation of the ToolBar.

```c
// in WinMain
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icce;
icce.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
icce.dwICC = ICC_BAR_CLASSES | ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_USEREX_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&icce);

// called in WM_CREATE handler, hwnd is the handle of the main window
VOID BuildToolBar(HWND hwnd)
{
    HWND hTool;
    TBBUTTON tbb[3];
    TBADDBITMAP tbab;

    hTool = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS |TBSTYLE_FLAT | CCS_TOP | BTNS_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_TOOL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SendMessage(hTool, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
    SendMessage(hTool, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, (LPARAM)TBSTYLE_EX_HIDECLIPPEDBUTTONS);

    tbab.hInst = HINST_COMMCTRL;
    tbab.nID = IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR;
    SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBITMAP, 0, (LPARAM)&tbab);

    ZeroMemory(tbb, sizeof(tbb));
    tbb[0].iBitmap = STD_FILENEW;
    tbb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
    tbb[0].idCommand = ID_FILE_NEW;

    tbb[1].iBitmap = STD_FILEOPEN;
    tbb[1].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbb[1].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
    tbb[1].idCommand = ID_FILE_OPEN;

    tbb[2].iBitmap = STD_FILESAVE;
    tbb[2].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbb[2].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
    tbb[2].idCommand = ID_FILE_SAVEAS;

    SendMessage(hTool, TB_SETBUTTONSIZE, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(16, 16));
    SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBUTTONS, sizeof(tbb) / sizeof(TBBUTTON), (LPARAM)&tbb);
    SendMessage(hTool, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
}
```

So, **The Question Is:** Despite the bitmaps of the buttons, how can I get 3D look and feel for the tool bar, just like the Notepad++/Notepad2 example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's never any lack of toolbar choices.  Notepad++ uses a Rebar control, SDK page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It doesn't look like you got the visual styles manifest right.

Comment: @HansPassant The Rebar example on the SDK page showed a flat tool bar embedded in Rebar rather than the Notepad++ style. And the example on the "manifest" solution page showed the flat style, too. I wonder how Nodepad++ managed to make that tool bar style out of ToolBar/Rebar.

Comment: Well, Notepad++ is 'flat' on my machine and the screenshot you linked.  Watch out for an old version, taste and Windows versions change rapidly.

Comment: I can confirm Arie Shaw is right, default Win32 toolbar is same like image #1. And notepad2 -> image #3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Toolbar first and then Rebar.

the **rbBand.hbmBack** must be set to **NULL** to get modern look toolbar,
or remove **RBBIM_BACKGROUND** flag from the code below.

Here's how to create rebar:

```
HWND WINAPI CreateRebar (HWND hwndOwner)
{
    REBARINFO     rbi;
    REBARBANDINFO rbBand;
    RECT          rc;
    HWND   hwndCB, hwndRB;
    DWORD  dwBtnSize;

    hwndRB = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
        REBARCLASSNAME,
        NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |
        WS_CLIPCHILDREN | RBS_VARHEIGHT |
        CCS_NODIVIDER,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        hwndOwner,
        NULL,
        GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
        NULL);
    if (!hwndRB)
        return NULL;
    // Initialize and send the REBARINFO structure.
    rbi.cbSize = sizeof(REBARINFO);  // Required when using this
    // structure.
    rbi.fMask = 0;
    rbi.himl = (HIMAGELIST)NULL;
    if (!SendMessage(hwndRB, RB_SETBARINFO, 0, (LPARAM)&rbi))
        return NULL;
    // Initialize structure members that both bands will share.
    rbBand.cbSize = sizeof(REBARBANDINFO);  // Required
    rbBand.fMask = RBBIM_COLORS | RBBIM_TEXT | RBBIM_BACKGROUND |
        RBBIM_STYLE | RBBIM_CHILD | RBBIM_CHILDSIZE |
        RBBIM_SIZE;
    rbBand.fStyle = RBBS_CHILDEDGE | RBBS_FIXEDBMP;
    rbBand.hbmBack = NULL;  //
    // Create the combo box control to be added.
    hwndCB = CreateWindowW(TEXT("COMBOBOX"), NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_HASSTRINGS | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
        410, 20, 120, 110, (HWND) NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);;
    // Set values unique to the band with the combo box.
    GetWindowRect(hwndCB, &rc);
    rbBand.lpText = "Combo Box";
    rbBand.hwndChild = hwndCB;
    rbBand.cxMinChild = 0;
    rbBand.cyMinChild = rc.bottom - rc.top;
    rbBand.cx = 200;

    // Add the band that has the combo box.
    SendMessage(hwndRB, RB_INSERTBAND, (WPARAM)-1, (LPARAM)&rbBand);


    // Get the height of the toolbar.
    dwBtnSize = SendMessage(toolbar1, TB_GETBUTTONSIZE, 0, 0);

    // Set values unique to the band with the toolbar.
    rbBand.lpText = "Tool Bar";
    rbBand.hwndChild = toolbar1;
    rbBand.cxMinChild = 0;
    rbBand.cyMinChild = HIWORD(dwBtnSize);
    rbBand.cx = 250;

    // Add the band that has the toolbar.
    SendMessage(hwndRB, RB_INSERTBAND, (WPARAM)-1, (LPARAM)&rbBand);
    return (hwndRB);
}
```

Comment: Ah, it worked, thanks. It's been a long time since I last touched the WINAPI. I'm still having problem that the toolbar doesn't show up until you have put the mouse to the icons. I'll investigate that later.